# How to make VSS client in VS warn before merge?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, merge, visual-sourcesafe

When you use VSS client in VS and you execute check-in on some source files, in case of conflicts that can be merged, they are merged and AFTER that the dialog with info is displayed that the sources were merged.

How to configure it in such way, that the dialog will appear with info BEFORE merge showing me the differences?

*Visual Studio 2012, Visual Source Safe 8.0, please don't comment on the tools, company choice, not mine.*

Comment: Have u tried do first update and then check in?

Comment: @BorisIvanov, I want to change behavior of check-in from "merge-inform later" to "warn about merge in advance". Remembering that I have to update first is no go, because it does not change check-in behavior really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to Tools->Options->Source Control->Plugin settings, click Advanced button. Under General tab, set 'Use visual merge' to YES and try again to see how it works.